# hadoop.tmp.dir dont work in right location

Tags: hadoop, hive, config, hive-configuration

In my core-site.xml, I changed the `hadoop.tmp.dir` location in another big HHD (`/data/hadoop_tmp`), this HHD is not linux /tmp location, then formatted my namenode, started my dfs and yarn, I believe it worked.

But the default location appears in the same folder, and when I use hive, hive-jar is loaded in the default location (/tmp), my /tmp is too small and then hive job fails

I dont know why my config does not work.

Comment: hadoop.tmp.dir always appear /tmp, whatever is the hadoop.tmp.dir